# Python - Sorting in ascending order in a txt file

Tags: python, sorting

I had a huge document that I parsed using regex to give a txt file (json.dump) similar to the following:

```
{
    "stuff": [
        {
            "name": [
                "frfer", 
                "niddsi", 
            ], 
            "number": 11300, 
            "identifier": "Tsdsad"
        }, 
        {
            "name": [
                "Fast", 
                "Guard", 
                "Named", 
            ], 
            "number": 117900, 
            "identifier": "Pdfms"
        }, 
        {
            name: [
                "Fast", 
            ], 
            "number": 660, 
            "identifier": "Unnamed"
        },    
    ]
}
```

Now I would like to sort this document in ascending order based on the number. (i.e. "Pdfms" first, "Tsdsad" second, "Unnamed" third). I am unsure how to start this off in python, could anyone give me a point in the right direction? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you use python's [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module?

Comment: At least one reason: That's almost JSON, but not quite. At minimum, it needs to be up-leveled to valid JSON before the `json` module will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: That's not legitimate JSON. You have extra commas (JSON doesn't like `[a,b,c,]`; it insists on `[a,b,c]`) in the source, and you have some identifiers (the third instance of `name`, e.g.) that are not quoted. Ideally, you will improve your initial text file parsing and JSONification to fix those issues. Or you can handle those fixups on the fly, like this:

```
json_source = """
    ... your text data from above ...
"""

import re
BADCOMMA = re.compile(r',\s+\]')
json_source = BADCOMMA.sub(']', json_source)

BADIDENTIFIER = re.compile(r'\s+name:\s*')
json_source = BADIDENTIFIER.sub('"name":', json_source)
```

Beware, assuming you can fix every possible problem on the fly is a *fragile* pattern. Editing structured data files via regular expressions, likewise. Better to generate good JSON from the get-go.

Now, how to sort:

```
import json
data = json.loads(json_source)

data['stuff'].sort(key=lambda item: item['number'], reverse=True)
```

That does an in-place sort of the "stuff" array, by the "number" value, and reverses it (because your example of how you want the output suggests a descending rather than the typical ascending sort).

To demonstrate that the sort has done what you want, the `pprint` module can be handy:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Yields:

```
{u'stuff': [{u'identifier': u'Pdfms',
             u'name': [u'Fast', u'Guard', u'Named'],
             u'number': 117900},
            {u'identifier': u'Tsdsad',
             u'name': [u'frfer', u'niddsi'],
             u'number': 11300},
            {u'identifier': u'Unnamed', u'name': [u'Fast'], u'number': 660}]}
```